# Stocking date and time array in LocalDateTime array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of dates and an array of times. Now I want to stock them in the LocalDateTime array `result`. The size of the `result` is the size of `dates` multiplied by the size of `times` (3 days with 4 times each for example so the `result` size is 12).
I tried this code to stock everything into a different elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultaat.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dates.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < times.length; k++) {
            result[i] = LocalDateTime.of(dates[j], times[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

```
result= LocalTimeDate, dates = LocalDate, times = LocalTime
```

Now I don't know what I'm doing wrong but if I print out the elements, they all have the same information, date is the last date of the date array and time is last time of time array.

Any help is welcome thanks.

edit: i printed them out in the inner forloop and then every result is as it should be only when i want to print out a certain one outside the forloops for example result[12] it gives last date and last time

edit 2 :
i changed my code so that i don't overwrite the elements again and so again when i print them out in the loops it is fine and when i want to print out outside the loop it give again the problem as written before
new code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < times.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
            result[k] = LocalDateTime.of(dates[i], times[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it will solve your problem (probably not) but in the outer loop condition you have `i < resultaat.length` but inside the inner loop you use the `result` array: `result[i] = LocalDateTime.of(dates[j], times[k]);`. Isn't this an error?

Comment: well it does not give an error in my code just a warning that i'm running over an array manually

Comment: @insert_x not all errors will be detected by your compiler and give errors! Besides, I was not talking about compile errors or warning: what is the difference between the `resultaat` array and the `result` array? Why do you use the length of the first to iterate over the lather? or is it just a typo? I didn't find that very clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write to each element of array `result` only one time but you you're rewriting each element many times.

Let rename indexes `j` and `k` to `date` and `time`.

You want to get all pairs of date and time, right? So using only cycles with `date` and `time`, you can determine `i` knowing `date` and `time` and then write suitable value to `result[i]`.

To determine `i` knowing `date` and `time` draw a table such that `date` is index of row and `time` is index of column. Fill this table with indexes `i` and you will see how to get `i` knowing `j` and `k`.

```
\ time
d \  0  1  2
a 0  0  1  2
y 1  3  4  5
  2  6  7  8
  3  9 10 11
```

Comment: i think i changed my code now so that i don't rewrite each element, and by only using date and time, do you mean only use 2 forloops?

Comment: @insert_x, yes, I mean only use 2 forloops. Line 4 (which writes to result[i]) must be executed exactly (dates.length * time.length) times.

Comment: i don't know if i did it exaclty like you ment but i managed to fix it according to your information, i used a while loop with 2 forloops in it instead of 3 forloops, thanks for your help